# Изменение цвета картинки в picturebox

Tags: c#, изображения, picturebox

Имеется изображение синего квадрата, залитое в picturebox. Можно ли сделать его цвет (или оттенок) красным, без смены его на другое изображение или изменение цвета каждого пикселя?

Comment: Поместить поверх этого `PictureBox` какую-нибудь `Panel`, залитую полупрозрачным красным цветом.

Comment: проще вместо `picturebox` использовать `panel`, если вам нужен прямоугольник, заполненный одним цветом

Comment: Можно попробовать поменять цвет содержимого попиксельно, только это ужасно медленно и неэффективно.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно поверх `PictureBox` разместить панель, залитую полупрозрачным цветом.

Для тестирования создаём новый проект Windows Forms, в конструктор формы помещаем код:

```
public Form1()
{
    //InitializeComponent();

    // Создаём изображение - синий квадрат
    var bmp = new Bitmap(150, 150);
    var g = Graphics.FromImage(bmp);
    g.Clear(Color.Blue);

    var pictureBox = new PictureBox
    {
        Parent = this,
        Width = 200,
        Height = 200,
        BorderStyle = BorderStyle.FixedSingle
    };
    pictureBox.Image = bmp;

    // Создаём панель. Обратите внимание: её родитель - pictureBox
    var panel = new Panel
    {
        Parent = pictureBox,
        BackColor = Color.FromArgb(100, Color.Red),
        //Dock = DockStyle.Fill
        Size = pictureBox.Image.Size
    };
}
```

`Color.FromArgb(100, Color.Red)` - тут создаётся цвет с коэффициентом прозрачности 100 (может быть от 0 до 255; попробуйте поиграться с ним).

Если картинка занимает всю площадь пикчабокса, то у панели можно задать свойство `Dock = DockStyle.Fill` (размер при этом не задаём). В противном случае, задаём такие же размеры, как у изображения.